# Format of the manuscript at the revision stage

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I recently submitted a paper to an Elsevier Journal (Biomedical Signal Processing and Control). I wrote the paper using the Elsevier article class (elsarticle.cls) with the option "review" which is one column format (text width = 12.5 cm) the final print copy as can be seen in published papers is two-column format (text width = 18.5 cm), when I was waiting a response from the editor I reread the paper carefully trying to correct possible errors and prepared it in a two-column format so that it matches as possible the final published layout.

Now I received an email for minor revisions but I found some comments about this topic, most of them say **"to send the revised manuscript in single-column format and let the journal worry about which of the formats they use in the end"**, now if I worked by the last advice and since the preprint layout uses a larger line width, I did not face problem with displayed the long equations but in two-column format the long equation will overlap.

Is the Latex expert (person specifically employed to do the layout of the journals) Takes upon himself the formation of the paper in two-column format (for example : break the equations in the appropriate points)?

Another chose, if I put a figure of 10 cm of width it looks fine in one column format but in two-column format if I put it as one column (`\begin{figure}`) it will overlap, and if I put it as two-column (`\begin{figure*}`) maybe it looks much smaller and if the Latex expert they use Latex instructions to reduce or enlarge the figure maybe it loose its nice shape.

Finally,as I said before I have two-column format it Much like the final published layout, should I sent the two-column format or one column format?

Comment: Did you check the "submission guidelines", "author guidelines" or "guidelines for authors" or similar? Some journals have layout people that take care of everything - there you should submit a word or similar version of the text, and figures in separate files. Others expect that the author takes care of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewers are concerned with the technical content of your paper, not the formatting.

Even if you're using a LaTeX-based style sheet, it's not necessary to worry about making sure everything fits within the margins. If the paper is accepted, the journal will probably work on your paper to make sure it follows their style guidelines when published.

So just worry that the content is correct, and submit a single-column paper for the reviewers to read. It'll make their lives easier, which will thus make your life easier. (And you won't waste time fiddling with LaTeX!)

Comment: I would just add that you should have a working plan for breaking your equations once the paper gets accepted. I mean, if you have long unbreakable equations, you better simplify them now then after.

Comment: @yo': But the journal will probably do it their own way. You'll just need to make sure that the typesetting doesn't change your intentions. (I had an article where they completely screwed up the math.)